# How to ignore Execution time of Google script and JS

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have for loop here for calling API calls from ticketmaster website and import in google sheets. The problem is I can't make many API calls at once I have to wait about 1 second.

So when I make the loop wait 1 second for example if the array has 40 element I wait 40 sec.
No problem with that due to the massive data but when the fucntion wait it gives an error of execution time limit, **I need to set the execution time unlimited.**

```
for (var Veunue_id1 = 0; Veunue_id1 < Venue_Id_List.length; Veunue_id1++) {


  var Venue_API_Url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/venues?apikey=" + API_key + "&keyword=" + Venue_Id_List[Veunue_id1] + "&locale=*";


  // ImportJSON(url, "/","noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders");
  // console.log(ImportJSON(url, "/", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders"));

  //  console.log("Veuneid" + Veunue_id + Venue_Id_List.length);
  

  results = results.concat(ImportJSON(Venue_API_Url, "/_embedded/venues/id", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders"));
  console.log(results);

// wait1 second
 Utilities.sleep(1000);



}
```

Answer (score 1):

This a common issue, especially when working with heavy data API. General approach is:

1. Run as much as you can, until timeout(6 min) is close
2. Save loaded data
3. Store some indicator on there to resume on next run
4. On next run, repeat from position saved in 3)
5. Put this on trigger.

Example code based on your situation (not tested)

```
function SimpleTimer(timeout){
  var start = Date.now();
  this.getElapsed = () => Date.now() - start;
  this.isTimeout = () => this.getElapsed() > timeout;  
}

function resetProgress(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last', '-1')
}

function test_SimpleTimer() {
  var timer = new SimpleTimer(4*60*1000) // 4 min;

  var start = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last') || '-1';

  for (var Veunue_id1 = parseInt(start) + 1; Veunue_id1 < Venue_Id_List.length && ! timer.isTimeout(); Veunue_id1++) {
    var Venue_API_Url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/venues?apikey=" + API_key + "&keyword=" + Venue_Id_List[Veunue_id1] + "&locale=*";       

    results = results.concat(ImportJSON(Venue_API_Url, "/_embedded/venues/id", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders"));

    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last', '' + Veunue_id1)
  }
    // SAVE YOUR DATA HERE, NEXT CALL WILL PROCEED FROM LAST STEP

}
```

Comment: I added the code to the script for the first time I ran the script it was working. Now I only Get Empty Arrays. On google sheets When I call the fcuntion it gives me this Error `#REF!` `refernce not exist`

Comment: Yes it doesn't enter the loop I due to the timer condition.

Comment: When I debug `Veunue_id1` I get 40 and it should be 0 I added this  ` var Veunue_id1 =0` in the begin and after the loop and still get 40!

Comment: It's this line whenn the value assigned to start it turns to 40 again so how I resst after the loop? 
`var start =   PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last') || '-1';`

Comment: I fixed the part of `var start =   PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last') || '-1'; `
but it still get execution time  Error. when the value became for example 20-35 I mean in the middle of the loop I get the data the length of `Venue_Id_List.length` is 40  from 20-39 the code runs normally. is there something we can add?